# How to set that a table foreign key value must be same in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

For example that i have 4 tables, that is Student, School,Tour and TourAttend. Tours are organised on a school basis and there will never be students from more than one school on the same tour.

### School

SchoolID Primary key
SchoolName

### Student

StudentID primary key
SchoolID Foreign key
StudentName

### Tour

TourID  Primary key
TourName

### TourAttend

TourAttendID Primary key
TourID Foreign Key
StudentID Foreign Key

Example of value

```
Student      School      
Student1    School1    
Student2    School1     
Student3    School2
```

How do i ensure that students that attend to 1 Tour that is come from exact same school, which mean if student that come from school1 attended the tour, school2 cannot be attend that tour?

Comment: "Tours are organised on a school basis" - then why isn't this modelled by `SchoolID` appearing in `Tour`? And once you have that, you can also include the column in `TourAttend`. And then you can declare additional keys/FKs to enforce the structure you're aiming for?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever There is one of my issue with the design is If i puting SchoolID itself only, i dont know which student is attending.

Comment: I'm not saying to *replace* any columns. I'd saying to add *additional* columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments, you can achieve this by adding the `SchoolID` column in the tables it's currently missing from:

```
CREATE TABLE Tour (
    TourID tinyint not null,
    TourName varchar(37) not null,
    SchoolID bigint not null,
    constraint PK_Tour PRIMARY KEY (TourID),
    constraint FK_Tour_School FOREIGN KEY (SchoolID) references School (SchoolID),
    constraint UQ_Tour_School UNIQUE (TourID, SchoolID)
)
```

So now, as in your narrative, each tour is associated with a *single* school. That's good, now how about the attendance?

```
CREATE TABLE TourAttend (
    TourAttendID smallint not null,
    TourID tinyint not null,
    StudentID char(1) not null,
    SchoolID bigint not null,
    constraint PK_TourAttend PRIMARY KEY (TourAttendID),
    constraint FK_TourAttend_Tour FOREIGN KEY (TourID)
          references Tour (TourID),
    constraint FK_TourAttend_Student FOREIGN KEY (StudentID)
          references Student (StudentID),
    constraint FK_TourAttend_XRefTour FOREIGN KEY (TourID,SchoolID) 
          references Tour (TourID, StudentID),
    constraint FK_TourAttend_XRefStudent FOREIGN KEY (StudentID, SchoolID) 
          references Student (StudentID, SchoolID)
)
```

(You will probably have to add a unique constraint in the `Student` table, across `StudentID` and `SchoolID`, in the same way as I did in `Tour` above, before creating the above `FK_TourAttend_XRefStudent` foreign key).

You now have some redundant foreign key constraints, but I often leave these in place, just for documentary purposes.